# Is there a SaaS for stress testing with user defined scenarios?

Tags: saas, stress-testing

I'm looking for a SaaS that let me do Stress Test with my own scenarios. I don't want to do them from my local machine because I want the most realistic scenario possible.

Best,

I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a number of services available - you should probably be searching for "load testing service".

I'll point out the free version of our product: [Load Tester LITE](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html). The LITE version provides testing of simple scenarios for free with no limit on the number of simulated users, but the use of our cloud engines to generate the load is not free (you can use your own hardware to generate load, if you like, for free).  There are other restrictions as well.

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction. Before asking in SO I founded some services but your answer helped me to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest searching for "load testing as as service" and not just "load testing service" (the latter will return some results that provide professional services.)

It really depends on your needs.

I work for [BlazeMeter](http://BlazeMeter.com) (we're kinda like JMeter on steroids as a service).
We offer both a paid and free tier depending on your needs.